# Inicialización: corchetes { }, asignación =, y otras formas

Tags: c++

¿ Los corchetes `{ ... }` representan lo mismo que el operador de asignación `=` ?

- Si la respuesta es si, ¿Cuando debería usarlos?
- Si la respuesta es no, ¿ Que representan ?

Por ejemplo, en este código:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    int &&rref{ 5 }; //¿que representan los corchetes? 
    rref = 10;
    std::cout << rref << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Los corchetes `{ ... }` representan lo mismo que `=` ?

**No**.

El tema de la inicialización en C++ es bastante amplio, como podemos observar en [su documentación (en inglés)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

- *Value initialization*

  Esta es la inicialización realizada cuando una variable se construye con un inicializador vacío.

  ```
  Clase instancia{ };
  Clase{ };
  new Clase{ };
  ```
- *Direct initialization*

  Inicializa un objeto a partir de un conjunto explícito de argumentos de constructor.

  ```
  Clase instancie { arg };
  ```
- *List initialization*

  Inicializa un objeto desde una lista-de-inicialización.

  ```
  Clase instancia { arg1, arg2, ... };
  Clase { arg1, arg2, ... };
  new Clase { arg1, arg2, ... };
  Clase { Clase variable-miembro { arg1, arg2, ... }; };
  Clase instance = { arg1, arg2, ... };
  función( { arg1, arg2, ... } );
  return { arg1, arg2, ... };
  instancia[ { arg1, arg2, ... } ];
  instancia = { arg1, arg2, ... };
  Clase( { arg1, arg2, ... } );
  Clase { Clase variable-miembro = { arg1, arg2, ... }; };
  ```
- *Aggregate initialization* (ver [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization))

  Inicializa un agregado desde una lista-de-inicialización.

  ```
  Clase instancia = { arg1, arg2, ... };
  Clase instance { arg1, arg2, ... };
  Clase instancia = { .designator = arg1 , .designator { arg2 } ... }; (C++20)
  Clase instancia { .designator = arg1 , .designator { arg2 } ... }; (C++20)
  Clase instancia( arg1, arg2, ... ); (c++20)
  ```

Como habrás observado, hay distintas formas de inicialización que comparten sintaxis; el empleo de una u otra es automático por parte del compilador, y depende del **tipo** de la instancia a inicializar. Es un tema **bastante** extenso.

En el código que muestras, estás declarando una variable `rref` como una *referencia de lado derecho*, y el compilador, debido al tipo utilizado (`int`) la está inicializando utilizando la `Direct initialization`.